# How to resolve errors on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task where i need debug some macro. On our sytem we changed columns for example, before we have price on column C now we have on B. when i run file its end work here :

```
For I = 23 To Sheets("start").Range("B22").End(xlDown).row

If Day(FileDateTime(path & Sheets("Start").Cells(I, 3))) = Day(Date) Then

Workbooks.Open (path & Sheets("Start").Cells(I, 3))

Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.rows.Count, 26)).Copy

main_file.Sheets("holdings").Activate
```

Could you explaine what is is I = 23 ? That's column I ? and what .Cells(I, 3)))

Comment: `I` is just a variable and in this algorithm it will be a row number. Thus, you are looping from row 23 to the the first empty row below cell B22 (=`.Range("B22").End(xlDown).row`)

Comment: Cells: `Cells(Row,Column)` so if you want to look at `B` change the `3` to `2`.

Comment: And `.Cells(I, 3)` is the cell located on row I, column "C"

Comment: When i edited i got error : Run time rror -r Överflow

Comment: Make sure `I` is declared `As Long`. You're looking for a statement that looks like `Dim I As Integer`; "Integer" is a 16-bit numeric data type, and the number of rows on a worksheet exceeds its maximum value of 32,767 by several orders of magnitude: `I` will overflow whenever any code attempts to assign it to any value greater than 32,768.

Comment: What did you edit? What line caused the error?  What are your declared variable types? What are the values of the variables in the line that caused the error at the time of the error?

Comment: ^ all of this. Please [edit] the post to clarify what the problem is and provide code that clearly reproduces the problem.